# How do you integrate the following function?

Tags: calculus

> $$\int \frac{8}{x^{-1}+2}\,dx$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMrQz.png)

The answer is
$$4x-2\ln|2x+1|+C.$$
[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm7Ur.png)

But how do you reach that answer without integration by parts?

Comment: Your integrand is $\frac {8x}{1+2x}=\frac {4(1+2x)-4}{1+2x}$.

Comment: Your first step should be $$\frac 8{x^{-1}+2} = \frac 8{x^{-1}+2}\left(\frac xx\right) = \frac{8x}{1+2x}$$

Comment: Question looks ugly, could you copy and paste the following as an edit: > $$\int \frac{8}{x^{-1}+2}$$  
 
 
 The answer is  $4x-2\ln|2x+1|+C$. But how do you reach that answer without integration by parts?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

We multiply the numerator and denominator by $x$, and then we have the following: 
$$\int \frac{8}{x^{-1}+2}dx=\int \frac{8x}{1+2x}dx=\int \frac{-4+4+8x}{1+2x}dx \\ =\int \frac{-4}{1+2x}dx+\int \frac{4+8x}{1+2x}dx \\ =-2\ln |1+2x|+4\int \frac{1+2x}{1+2x}dx \\ =-2\ln |1+2x|+4\int dx \\ =-2\ln |1+2x|+4x+C$$

Comment: Did you forget a minus sign at the end?

Comment: Yes, you are right!! I edited it... Thanks for noticing it!! :-) @frosh

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{8}{x^{-1}+2}=\frac{8x}{1+2x}\stackrel{long \: division}{=}4-\frac{4}{1+2x}$$

$$\Downarrow$$

$$\int \frac{8}{x^{-1}+2}dx=\int \bigg(4-\frac{4}{1+2x}\bigg)dx=4x-2\ln|2x+1|+C$$

where we used

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{ax+b}dx = \frac{1}{a} \ln |ax + b| 
\end{equation}}$$